# Angular js filter with rails incorrectly functioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Hi I am trying to use angular filtering in my rails app,but I do not know why it's not behaving in the correct way.

So I have a gender dropdown selection on which i filter my listings array.

Here are the codes:

/*listing.html.erb*/

```
<div class="ui page grid">
  <div class="column">
    <form class="ui form">
      <div class="six fields">
        <div class="field">
         <label>Gender</label>
         <%=select(:listing,:gender,options_for_select([['Male','Male',{class:'item'}],['Female','Female',{class:'item'}]]),{prompt:'Gender'},{:'ng-model'=>'listing1.gender',class:'ui dropdown gender'})%>
       </div>

       </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>


<div class="ui divided items" ng-controller="ListingController" ng-init="init(<%=@listings.to_json %> )" >
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="listing in listings | filter:{'gender':listing1.gender}">
    {{listing1.gender}}
      <div class="image">

      </div>
      <div class="content listing_content">
        <i class="right floated large like icon"></i>
        <i class="right floated large star icon"></i>

        <%=link_to '{{listing.title}}','listings/{{listing.id}}',class:'header'%>
        <div class="meta">
          <span class="cinema">Posted On
          <%= @date = '{{listing.created_at}}'  %>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          {{listing.love_for_pets}}
        </div>


        <div class="extra listing_price">
          <div class="right floated ui circular facebook icon button">
            <i class="facebook icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="right floated ui circular twitter icon button">
            <i class="twitter icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="right floated ui circular google plus icon button">
            <i class="google plus icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="ui teal tag label"><i class="rupee icon"></i>{{listing.price}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
```

It is getting all the data properly,everything is working fine,except for the filter.When i select female ,it gives me filtered output but for male I get all the listings.

Can someone please help in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting all results for "Male" is because the filter, as it's being used, returns partially matching results. To get an exact match within your filtering, modify your `ng-repeat` to this:

```
ng-repeat="listing in listings | filter:{gender : listing1.gender : true}
```

This should return strictly "Male" or "Female", and not match *male* to the partially matching fe*male* results.

Check out the docs on `filter`, specifically the arguments section that covers this option.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much Zoran, that worked perfectly.Exactly what I needed.Also can you guide me in the correct way of passing my rails instance variable @listings value to the angular controller,coz right now it goes to the init function and becoz of which when i inspect element I see an entire json of listings inside my div ,which I feel may not be the correct way of doing.So can you guide me in that.